# Static variable in Spring session bean on a cluster

Tags: java, spring, session, static, cluster-computing

I have a Spring bean with scope session and it implements Serializable. My application is deployed on a cluster of 3 nodes. Session replication is enabled in the cluster.
One of my variable inside the session scoped bean is static variable. I understand session replication will make use of the serialization. So when the session replication happens will my static variable also will be replicated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using a static variable for? Say there are two different values for the static variable on two different servers, what value would you expect it to end up with?

Comment: It is a static final String variable which store values of some string literals. There is no case of two different values for it.

Comment: In that case it'll be instantiated with that value, so all the sessions will have the same value anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I am working on tomcat session replication in a cluster. I too got the same doubt and tried to figure it out by trying to replicate static values in cluster.

I tried to change the value of the static variable, and stopped the current node. When the request goes to other node in the cluster(as the current node is down ), I observed that static variable is not holding the current changed value but with the value that is initialized while loading the class.

So static values doesn't get replicated in the cluster.

Comment: @Rakesh If my answer helped you then please vote for it